# Angular Local Server not working but laravel local server works

Tags: angular

So i've been assigned a project that consists of laravel backend and angular front end. I do not know anything about angular so im still learning but i know laravel. However, right now the local server for angular in my case is not working. I've followed instruction thoroughly on how to deploy it locally but the error i have in the browser is "Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)". The page is blank. But if i run php artisan serve on my laravel folder, everything works. Frontend and backend etc. These are the instructions given for local deployment.

1. Open sourcecode/proxy.conf.json file and update target url there to the base url of the site. For example: http://localhost/my-site. To test this open http://localhost/my-site/secure/bootstrap-data in the browser and make sure it's working.
   Important:
   It needs to be a local server url (localhost) and not your online site url. It should be the same url that can be seen in "admin > settings > general" page or inside ".env" file (APP_URL).
2. CD into sourcecode directory via terminal and install dependencies:  npm install
3. Run  npm start command from terminal. If previous steps were completed properly, you should be able to access local server at http://localhost:4200 url. Code will automatically re-compile and refresh the browser after detecting changes to files inside sourcecode directory.

I did all that and ended up with a blank page. Also I am confused as to which server should i run locally to test my codes? Laravel side or angular

Comment: you start your local angular project with "ng serve" or "npm start". It starts a server at localhost:4200. Laravel usually starts a server at localhost:8000 (php artisan serve). You have to cd in your angular app first. Additionally you have to start the laravel server. If the angular project is new you should a welcome page instead of a blank page. I Would suggest to get angular up running first and then focus on connecting to laravel since starting angular is really easy.

Comment: The project isnt new. There's like tons of files and codes. If i start laravel and run the site using the laravel url, everything works. It's working like it should even without starting angular. If i start angular and laravel and open the angular link, it's blank. I have cd into my angular app already.

Comment: How is your project structured? Do you use laravel for a REST API or as a full MVC project with blade templates? Please take a look inside the index.html file in the root directory of your angular app to see if there is anything inside.

Comment: Well it works now after i setup another fresh folder and followed the instructions again. I think it's somewhat related to the APP_URL in the env file. The one that wasnt working url was 127.0.0:8000 but the one that's working is localhost/foldername